# Localizing FirebaseUI Auth

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, firebaseui

I am a swift newbie so please bear with me. I have successfully integrated FirebaseUI into my app. I now wish to localize the strings for Dutch. My whole project is in Dutch so I do not have any localization in the project since it is all hard coded in the storyboard. The [FirebaseUI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseAuthUI/README.md#custom-strings) say that you should:

```
// Swift
authUI?.customStringsBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle() // Or any custom bundle.
```

But I am not sure where to actually place the strings file in the project (or how) or if I should be using a custom bundle?

I have spent a whole day playing around with bundles but without success. Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work eventually:

1. Add a strings file called FirebaseAuthUI.strings. I copied the content of this file from [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseAuthUI/Strings/en.lproj/FirebaseAuthUI.strings)
2. Use the following code when you create the controller to handle sign in:

Code:

```
if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FirebaseAuthUI", ofType: "strings") {
    let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath)
    authUI?.customStringsBundle = bundle;
}
```

Don't forget to translate the strings in step 1.

Good luck